# Reading text using scanner, storing in array and outputting uppercase using for each loop Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have to write a program to read in 10 names from a user (keyboard scanner) and store them in an array.  Then loop through the array and display the names in upper case (using a for each loop to display them all). How do I do it? At the moment I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Names
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner nameScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] names = new String[10];
        String[] namesUpper = new String[10];

        System.out.print("Enter a name : ");
        names=nameScan.next(); 


        namesUpper=names.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("Names in upper case: "+namesUpper);
    } 
}
```

---

So far I have this, but still not working. Where am I going wrong please? Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class NamesReAD
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
            Scanner nameScan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String[] names = new String[10];


            for (int i = 0 ; i < names.length ; i++) {
                System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
                names[i] = nameScan.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            }
            nameScan.close();
            System.out.println("Here is name"+names);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you stuck with?

Comment: I don't know where to go from Starting the array off and then using a for each loop

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < names.length ; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
    names[i] = nameScan.nextLine().toUpperCase();
}
```

This section would work except the .toUpperCase(); It will not change the names to uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a `for`-loop to traverse the array(s) and put the appropriate data at each index. For instance,

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < names.length ; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
    names[i] = nameScan.nextLine();
}
```

This will ask the user for a name 10 times, and will fill the `names` array with whatever the user inputs. Now, you don't really have to create a second array (`namesUpper`); you can just loop over `names` again and print `names[i].toUpperCase()` (or use a [`for`-each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop as you suggested, but the idea is the same).

---

As you have it now, these two lines won't compile:

```
names = nameScan.next(); 
namesUpper = names.toUpperCase();
```

since 1) `names` is an array and `nameScan.next()` returns a string and 2) `names` has no method called `toUpperCase`.

---

**EDIT**: Or, you could just store the names as upper-case when you add them to the `names` array:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < names.length ; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
    names[i] = nameScan.nextLine().toUpperCase();
}
```

Then you wouldn't have to worry about anything when you print the contents of the array.